# ¿Cómo guardar screenshot en variable?

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que toma una captura de pantalla y la guarda en la memoria interna.

Yo quiero hacer que la captura la guarde en una variable en vez de la memoria interna.

Aquí está mi código:

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName=timeStamp +".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: En este link puedes encontrar lo que buscas... http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-in-android.html

Comment: Posibles fuentes del código: [Capture Picture - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture), [Saving Media - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media), y [Saving camera picture in a file, file not created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991526/saving-camera-picture-in-a-file-file-not-created)

Answer (score 0):

La imagen ya la tienes guardada en memoria, en realidad es la variable `image` de tipo [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html):

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
 fos.close();
```